# Pass arguments to flutter activity from java

Tags: android, flutter

I have an android native application with a flutter module.

I need to open an activity from java and send some arguments to flutter. Here is my code where I call my flutter "activity":

```
startActivity(
       FlutterActivity
                 .withCachedEngine(flutterNameEngine)
                 .build(this)
);
```

I can do this:

```
..build(this).putExtra("arg_1","Hello world")
```

But I don't know how to receive the data on my flutter / dart code. Any idea?

Comment: Use platform channels. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#example

Comment: I was thinking about it, I hoped there was another way. Thanks

Comment: @user667634 I need help, im trying to create my activity extending FlutterActviy but it isnt working, where should I register my channel?

Comment: Fixed thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59449226/3994630